# Infinite Series arising in Laplace transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, laplace-transform, laurent-series

I'm trying to understand how the answer was computed for the following infinite series:

$\sum _ { x = 1 } ^ { \infty } e ^ { - s x } p q ^ { x - 1 } = \frac { p e ^ { - s } } { 1 - q e ^ { - s } }$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $e^{-sx}pq^{x-1}=(e^{-s}q)^{x-1} \cdot pe^{-s}$. You know the sum of a geometric series, right?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Mindlack. I know very little about geometric series (and series in general) though. I guess this now should look like some expression for which the sum is well known. I will try to compute this using online solver (although it could not give me an answer for the original form).

Comment: I got it now :), many thanks @Mindlack. Just needed to replace accordingly in $S _ { \infty } = \sum _ { n = 1 } ^ { \infty } a r ^ { n - 1 } = \frac { a _ { } } { 1 - r ^ { } }$